# Can free flying twin drag rudders be mounted on a stabilator, aerodynamically speaking?

Tags: aerodynamics

Can free flying twin drag rudders be mounted on a stabilator on an ultralight, aerodynamically speaking, or would it be disadvantageous?

I understand free flying rudders need up to 40% less area than a classical vertical tail arrangmenent with a stabilizer and rudder. Source: Zenith, Flying on your own Wings

I also understand that stabilators  need up to 15% less tail volume than a horizontal stabilizer and elevator.
Source: http://www.ae.metu.edu.tr/~ae451/geometry_sizing&configuration.pdf

I also understand an H-tail can be used as end plates to increase the effectiveness of an elevator by changing it's lift distribution, from an elliptical one to a rectangular one, reducing the elevator area required even more.

I also understand that twin drag rudders are more effective than standard
rudders in a twin rudder configuration, reducing the required area even more.

What about combining the two?

Can twin free flying differential drag rudders be mounted on the end of a stabilator?

See pic below.

[image: Stabilator mounted twin rudders]

Comment: The question is a bit vague and too general.  Are you asking whether it is physically possible, permitted by the FAA, economically feasible, aerodynamically advantageous, or...?

Comment: What is a free flying rudder?

Comment: @Super I googled for it and didn't find anything so I assume it's invented by OP, hence asking for clarification in the comments has a higher chance of success.

Comment: @ Super: A free flying rudder is a rudder without a vertical stabilizer. They have been around a long time. See Zenith 701.

Comment: @user3528438 Sorry about that. I didn't correctly interpret your meaning, it was a fault on my end.

Comment: @Fred I believe your comment is directed toward user3528438

Comment: @Fred The modern term seems to be "all-moving" or "all-flying" although I'm more familiar with "all-moving". All moving rudder in a H configuration will be very awkward structurally. E-2/C-2 is probably the largest rudder to stabilizer ratio you can get.

Comment: @user3528438: What is E-2/C-2?

Comment: @Fred Grumman E-2 Hawkeye/C-2 Greyhound

Comment: For the endplate rudders to work as intended, the whole H tail has to be one single rigid element. Therefore it has to be hinged at the middle of the horizontal H bar. This hinge has to allow for both pitch and yaw deflection. One good example of this is Santos-Dumont demoiselle n°19 cruciform tail. Now since ultralight are meant to be ultralight, extra structural weight needed for the horizontal surface to support rudders plus hinge mechanism may nullify aerodynamic endplates benefits.

Comment: Furthermore, H tail produces far more interference drag than for instance V-tail. (Lazair inverted V-tail is typically not an all moving Vtail since it requires strong weathervaning due to lack of fuselage lateral surface.)

Comment: @qq jkztd: Why do you say the end plate stabilator would have to be one piece? Wouldn't it just be like wing tip rudders?